# popping a group of at most N entries from the left of a deque in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I want to pop at most `limit` items from the left of a `collections.deque`.

```
def popAll(q, limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        result = list(q)
        q.clear()
    else:
        result = []
        try:
            for _ in xrange(limit):
                result.append(q.popleft())
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return result
```

This appears to work but seems... clunky. Is there a more "pythonic" way? `deque` objects don't support slicing.

*NOTE:* for my purposes, I don't need an inherently threadsafe answer since I am going to be wrapping access to the deque inside a `threading.RLock()` access.

Comment: Are any other threads reading or writing from this deque while you're performing this operation? Do you want the multi-pop operation to be atomic from the viewpoint of other readers?

Comment: I don't need thread safety; I'm wrapping this in a `threading.RLock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I might do it:

```
def popAll(q, limit=None):
    return [q.popleft() for _ in xrange(min(limit or sys.maxsize, len(q)))]
```

Or maybe like this:

```
def popAll(q, limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        limit = sys.maxsize
    return [q.popleft() for _ in xrange(min(limit, len(q)))]
```

Note that the two examples differ in the behavior of `popAll(q, 0)`. In the first example, that returns the entire queue. In the second, it returns an empty list.

Comment: `xrange`? (this is Python 2)

Comment: Also, you'll want to document the behavior of `popAll(q, 0)`, which varies between my answer and the code in your question.

Comment: I like it for the most part... the `sys.maxsize` is bugging me though

Comment: oh, yeah, good point about 0. I went by the literal text of my question where I said "at most `limit` items" so `limit=0` should return an empty list. (and not well-defined for negative values.)

Comment: I've edited my answer and given you code for either meaning of `0`.

Comment: cool, thanks! On my PC it looks like this is faster, too, by about 30-50% depending on the number of items popped.

Comment: I suppose you could also do `limit = len(q)` rather than `limit = sys.maxsize`

Answer (score 1):

In case it is an iterable, you can use `itertools.islice` and then remove:

```
from itertools import islice

def popAll(q, limit=None):
    result = list(islice(q, limit))
    if limit is None or limit >= len(q):
        q.clear()
    else:
        for _ in range(limit):
            q.popleft()
    return result
```

In case the `limit` is thus not `None`, we calculate first the number of items we can remove (this is the minimum of the number of items in `q`, and the limit). In case `limit` is `None` or greater than or equal to zero, it is more efficient to simply `clear()` the deque, otherwise we iterate over the elements and remove them one at a time.

Comment: I said it's a deque, not a list, which doesn't support slicing.

Comment: @JasonS: I came up with a better idea that uses iterable slicing (available for all iterables).